# Step by step HTML, adding in options

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website where the user will run through a website step by step to view more detail (Like a customer journey).

I have got the basic code set up, so this works well. However on some of the pages I want them to have options which will then determine the route they go down.

For example on the third step they can choose option 1 or option 2. If they choose option 1 then this will show the rest of the steps for option 1 only. With the same if they click option 2.

I have created a codepen here which hopefully makes a little more sense: - https://codepen.io/scottYg55/pen/PowMawY

As you can see, step 3 is where they can choose an option. I also will be adding in more option functionality of some other steps too.

I have tried using the `remove()` function, so when the user clicks option 1 this then removes all the option 2 divs. However this isn't working correctly.

```js
$(function() {
  var $sections = $('.step');

  function navigateTo(index) {
    // Mark the current section with the class 'current'
    $sections
      .removeClass('current')
      .eq(index)
      .addClass('current');
    // Show only the navigation buttons that make sense for the current section:
  }

  function curIndex() {
    // Return the current index by looking at which section has the class 'current'
    return $sections.index($sections.filter('.current'));
  }

  // Previous button is easy, just go back
  $('.previous').click(function() {
    navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
  });

  // Next button goes forward iff current block validates
  $('.next').click(function() {
    if (
      $(this).hasClass("option-1-click")) {}
    navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
  });

  navigateTo(0); // Start at the beginning
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}

.step.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-steps">
  <div class="step">Step 1
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">Step 2
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">Step 3<br>Choose an option
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next option-1-click" href="#">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next option-2-click" href="#">Option 2</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step option-1">Option 1 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="step option-1">Option 1 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="step option-1">Option 1 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="step option-2">Option 2 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="step option-2">Option 2 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  <div class="step option-2">Option 2 details<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
</div>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand your problem, but `remove()` actually works fine.

I have added an extra step including all of your options, otherwise it will show the first div only. If you choose now option 1, it will show all option-1 divs. You can do the same with option 2.

EDIT: I saw that you planned on having a previous button. Then I would suggest you to use `hide()` instead of `remove()` so that you can always show again the other options.

```js
$(function() {
  var $sections = $('.step');

  function navigateTo(index) {
    // Mark the current section with the class 'current'
    $sections
      .removeClass('current')
      .eq(index)
      .addClass('current');
    // Show only the navigation buttons that make sense for the current section:
  }

  function curIndex() {
    // Return the current index by looking at which section has the class 'current'
    return $sections.index($sections.filter('.current'));
  }

  // Previous button is easy, just go back
  $('.previous').click(function() {
    navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
  });

  // Next button goes forward iff current block validates
  $('.next').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("option-1-click")) {
        $('.option-2').remove();
      }
    if ($(this).hasClass("option-2-click")) {
        $('.option-1').remove();
      }
    navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
  });

  navigateTo(0); // Start at the beginning
});
```

```css
.step {
  display: none;
}

.step.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="all-steps">
  <div class="step">Step 1
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">Step 2
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">Step 3<br>Choose an option
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next option-1-click" href="#">Option 1</a></div>
    <div class="main-button"><a class="next option-2-click" href="#">Option 2</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="option-1">Option 1 details (1)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
    <div class="option-2">Option 2 details (1)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="option-1">Option 1 details (2)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
    <div class="option-2">Option 2 details (2)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="step">
    <div class="option-1">Option 1 details (3)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
    <div class="option-2">Option 2 details (3)<a class="next" href="#">Next</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Dialex, I only want the show the first option 1. Then if they click next from that div, it will bring the 2nd Option 1 div up etc..

Comment: Then wouldn’t it be possible to make this into multiple steps? Like I did, on the first step after choosing the option, you can add the first option-1, then another step, etc. I will update my answer in a few minutes

Comment: I updated my answer, check if it is the solution that you are looking for.

Comment: No im afraid this isnt working, I only want to show the steps of that option

Comment: Are you sure? When I choose Option 1, then only option 1 details shows up on next steps. I added the same function for Option 2 now.

Comment: That is correct, however when you see 'option 2 details' then the button doesnt work to take you to the next div

Comment: Yes it does, you don't see any difference because they have the same content. I have now added a number to each option, you will see that it works.

Comment: Agh okay I see! And then I can follow the same above for more options on say, step 10?

Comment: Yes exactly, you can do exactly the same thing. If you have a lot more options, then you can consider another solution but that's another question.

Comment: There will only ever be 2 options per step. But on multiple steps